# Error evaluating function `image-size`: Invalid JPG, marker table corrupted

Tags: image, jpeg

When I compile project I get error:

```
Error in plugin 'less'
Message:
    error evaluating function `image-size`: Invalid JPG, marker table corrupted
Details:
    type: Runtime
```

I can open image, it is fine.
This error had appeared recently, I don't know why, before that it worked good.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somehow it is connected with [imagemin](https://github.com/imagemin/imagemin-jpegtran) module and it's parameters. When `arithmetic` option set to false, this error disappear.